# Nested loops to remove diagonal elements of matrix

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, median

Suppose I have a 2-dimensional data (of the form 100x1) stored in X.
This is essentially for a kernel function, which is denoted as k(x, x'), where for instance instead of doing the complicated computations in the 9-dimensional space, we reach the same result within the 3-dimensional space by calculating the dot product of x -transpose and x. Maybe that can give a 100x100 matrix from a 100x1 to begin with?

How should I initialize `dist` such that I can use a condition given below

```
def median_cal(X):
    # X: n*1 matrix
    #dist = np.empty((len(X), len(X)), float)
    #aim: Calculate the median of the pairwise distance of $X$ below 

    [dist[i, j] for i in range(len(X)) for j in range(len(X)) if i != j]
    #print('dist',dist)
    
    h = np.median(distance.pdist(dist))   
    return h

h = median_distance(np.array([[1],[2],[4]]))
print('final: h')
print(h)
# answer should be 2.0 for this data
```

to remove the diagonal terms of the matrix? and then calculate the median of the remaining data points.

Comment: The matrix is one dimensional. 100 rows and 1 column. What diagonal you want to remove? Also, I don't get what you are doing in the line `[dist[i, j] for i in range(len(X)) for j in range(len(X)) if i != j]`

Comment: ℎ = ({||−||:≠,      ,=1,...,}).

essentially X is my data where in nx1 can be expressed as a nxn by correlating it to itself

Comment: So, this is essentially for a  kernel function, which is denoted as k(x, x'), where for instance instead of doing the complicated computations in the 9-dimensional space, we reach the same result within the 3-dimensional space by calculating the dot product of x -transpose and x. Maybe that can give a 100x100 matrix from a 100x1 to begin with

Comment: It does not yield `{||−||:≠, ,=1,...,}`. Also, do not use list comprehension everywhere. This is not really an appropriate way to do list comprehension.

Comment: I did use something like np.fill_diagonal(A, 0) but is corrupting some of my generated data. 

what would be the list comprehension approach to setting the diagonal location elements 0 and keeping rest same?
e.g.
meaning for a nx1 array, the first element changes to zero, rest remain the same.

Comment: You mean keep the diagonal as 0 and the rest as `||−||`?

Answer (score 0):

```
[dist[i, j] for i in range(len(X)) for j in range(len(X.T)) if i != j]
```

The above solved it for me. Transpose of the column vector was the key thing to note to introduce the columns of the square matrix

Comment: If you say so. The line has no effect whatsoever on dist matrix. I am not really sure at this point what you want to do.

Comment: The line does have an effect on dist. It replaces every i=j location with a 0. So for a nx1 array, the very first element becomes zero; doesn't necessarily have to be a square matrix.

for instance, np.array([[1],[2],[4]]) as input, it would return [[0],[2],[4]]

Comment: It doesn't. I ran the code to confirm it. Also, use normal for loops and not list comprehension.